# An Error when using sussex_nltk

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I receive this error when using

```
from sussex_nltk.corpus_readers import AmazonReviewCorpusReader
```

The error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sussex_nltk'
```

I tried to find it using nltk.download() but could not find any model with this name.

I read in http://users.sussex.ac.uk/~davidw/courses/nle/SussexNLTK-API/sussex_nltk.html that:

> The Sussex NLTK package provides extensions to the functionality
>   provided by the standard NLTK distribution, along with additional
>   corpora.

which might mean it is not part of the standard nltk, but could not find how can i load it or install it

Please advice

Comment: Where did you find this package? You won't be able to download it from nltk.download(). It is a separate library entirely. I checked the url to the documentation, and when I attempted to go back I got access denied. Are you meant to be given this package in a course, maybe? There is no git repository and it is not in pypi

Comment: @Neil thanks for your reply. I found it in some examples at github like this one
https://gist.github.com/language-engineering/3973277

Comment: Is there something specific you need from sussex_nltk that nltk can't provide? What are you trying to do? If you need this package, I would contact the details on this page and ask them how to access this package. http://www.taglaboratory.org/